# What equation would be used to be draw a curve like this?

Tags: interpolation

[image]

I have created a little visual based programming system and am not working on the visuals, if two nodes are connected and B.x<A.x then I want a curve to be drew in the fashion above.

Comment: Perhaps some function $x=a \cdot \sin(y) +b$.

Comment: I'm not exactly the best when it comes to maths, can I get it in terms of a.x, a.y, b.x and b.y? thanks

Comment: A cubic polynomial can make a plot like this

Comment: Try $x= ay^3 + by^2 + cy + d$. Experiment a little with the coefficients

Comment: What is c and d?